# Android RadioButton IsSelected is not working

Tags: android

I have a radio group defined with two buttons for black and color.  When I try to do a calculation based on the selection nothing happens.  Any idea why my radio buttons arent' working?  Thanks

```
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText startingAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                RadioButton black = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton color = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(startingAmt.getText().toString().trim())){


                TextView ***** = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                double  temp1 = 0.0,
                        endAmt = 0.0,
                        startAmt = 0.0;
                String answer;
                Editable editableValue1 = startingAmt.getText();
                startAmt = Double.parseDouble(editableValue1.toString());
                if(color.isSelected()){
                    temp1 = startAmt * 1.15;
                    endAmt = temp1 * .15;
                    endAmt = (double)Math.round(endAmt*10)/10;
                }
                if(black.isSelected()){
                    temp1 = startAmt * 1.10;
                    endAmt = temp1 * .10;
                    endAmt = (double)Math.round(endAmt*10)/10;
                }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead using `isSelected()` go for `isChecked()`.

Comment: Thanks!  I assumed it was selected lol you check a checkbox and select a radio button!

Answer (score 4):

Use the method [`isChecked`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29) instead of `isSelected`. Or you can use the [`getCheckedRadioButtonId`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29) on your `RadioGroup` that contains the two `RadioButtons`.